# Proving quotient space is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness, quotient-spaces

Let $X= \mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\}$ with the usual topology. Under the relation $R$, $(a,b)=(c,d)$ whenever $a=c<0$ and every other point is identified only with itself. Form the quotient space $Y= (\mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\} ) / R$.

I want to show that the Y is connected.

Here are my thoughts:

I think two approaches might work: showing that Y is path-connected or showing that Y can’t be disconnected ( via argument by contradiction).

I try the second approach: If $\{A,B\}$ is an open partition of $Y$ then wlog $A$ contains $[\{(0,0)\}]$. Then $[(B(0,r)\times \{0\}) \cup (B(0,r’)\times \{1\})] \subset A$. Hence B can’t be open ( or $B=\emptyset) $because it has “endpoints” $\{(r,0)\}$ and $\{(r,1)\}$. We get the desired contradiction.

Is this correct? Many thanks!

Comment: How can be $b<0$ if $b\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Whoops! Should be $c$! Edited it...

Comment: This would need to be justified: "Hence $B$ can’t be open (or $B=\emptyset$) because it has “endpoints” $\{(r,0)\}$ and $\{(r,1)\}$"  At the moment, I see no reason why it should follow from the previous statement.

Comment: Also, I think it would be easier to show $Y$ is path-connected.  It follows by a rather simple argument that the path-components of $\mathbb{R}\times \{0,1\}$ are $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}$.  Then under the relation, $(-1,0) R (-1,1)$.

Comment: Many thanks! Essentially my argument is that the set containing (the equivalence class) zero has to be everything because A (by openness) overlaps into the $\mathbb{R} \times {0}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times {1}$, each of which ( viewed individually) are connected.

Comment: So you are algo gluing $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$? In the definition of your relation it says $a=c<0$.

Comment: Ah yes... how silly of me. No the origin should not be glued! I will change it!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Regarding your comment on path connectedness. Could you explain this in more detail... I don’t quite follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite follow your argument. Nevertheless note that the only partition of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$ into two nonempty open sets would be given by $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}/R$ be the quotient map. If $\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}/R$ can be partitioned into nonempty open sets $A$ and $B$ then $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are nonempty open sets that partition $\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$. So without loss of generality you can assume that $f^{-1}(A)=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and $f^{-1}(B)=\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}$. But this is impossible by definition of $R$.

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit unsure why ℝ×{1}  and ℝ×{0} have to lie in separate sets.Is it because ℝ×{1} (similarly ℝ×{0}) is connected as a subspace of X?

Comment: @user exactly, so if for example both $A\cap \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\neq \emptyset$ and $B\cap \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\neq \emptyset$, for $A$ and $B$ two open sets, then $A\cap  \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ and $B\cap  \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ gives a partition of $ \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ into nonempty open sets, which is impossible because the space is connected.